# Initializing a char *tab[] with malloc/calloc

Tags: c, initialization, malloc, strcpy, calloc

I’m trying to initialize a char *tab[] and this causes segmentation fault, what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <float.h>
int main()
{
    char **cle_par = NULL;
    cle_par = (char**) calloc (22, sizeof (char *)+1);
    int y=0;
    for (y=0; y<22; y++);
    {
        cle_par[y]=(char *) malloc(45*sizeof(char));
    }
    strcpy(cle_par[0], "this_is_a_test");
}
```

Comment: Typo: extra semicolon: `for (y=0; y<22; y++);`  -> `for (y=0; y<22; y++)`

Comment: Another example of why an opening brace should **not** be on its own line.

Comment: What is the `+1` for in `sizeof (char *)+1`?

Comment: Oh god you're right.. I'm surprised there was no warning though. Thanks a lot

Comment: Why an array that holds pointers should be a double pointer and why in the heap?

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis: Which array? I just see a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a "typo" error which invalidates the for loop and makes it an empty loop.

`for (y=0; y<22; y++);`, the trailing semicolon makes the loop empty, and I believe it's not your intention. If you remove it. Your code should work fine.